# Error FaceBook tab app " Refused to display "?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook

> I had this error below when try to play my Facebook app

[image]

```
Response.Write("<script>window.location='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" +
                 facebookClientId + "&redirect_uri=https://" + host +
                 @"/FBcallback.aspx&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,publish_actions');</script>");
```

Comment: You can not open the login dialog inside an iframe, you have to call it in the top window instance, so `top.location.href='...'`

Comment: @CBroe   why I cannot open it inside the iframe , the hacker will hack the access token from url .

Comment: _“why I cannot open it inside the iframe”_ – because Facebook designed it that way, for the good and simple reason that the user should be able to check the URL, otherwise phishing would be too easy. _“the hacker will hack the access token from url”_ – nonsense, the only one who sees it is the user himself. The access token is tied to his account, so why would he “hack” himself?